# Why can't a cell indexer be mapped to a const int?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

With this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            const int TICKETSOURCE_COLUMN = 3;
            const int ABOUTSOMEID_COLUMN = 4;
            const int CATEGORYID_COLUMN = 5;
            const int CONTACTEMAIL_COLUMN = 6;

            textBoxTicketSource.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[TICKETSOURCE_COLUMN].Value);
            textBoxAboutLLSID.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[ABOUTSOMEID_COLUMN].Value);
            textBoxCategoryID.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[CATEGORYID_COLUMN].Value);
            textBoxContactEmail.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[CONTACTEMAIL_COLUMN].Value); 
        }
```

I'm getting this err msg:

*"System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*

I have two questions about this:

1) Why is this a problem/how should I do this instead?

2) Is the RowEnter() event the best place to put this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `const int` is not the problem here...

Either you have mis-numbered them or, more likely, `CurrentRow` is `null`

Post the stacktrace, and simply use the debugger.

Comment: Yes, the CurrentRow is null on the first RowEnter(); so, I moved the code to the CellClick() event and it works just fine.